# First row is calculated differently than all other rows and all rows but first row is conditioned upon previous row

Tags: python, finance

I have a df of columns with tickers with rows of daily returns and the index is a datetime index

> ```
>             SPY      IWM       TLT                                                                          
> 2016-01-04  0.914939  0.998960  1.014094  
> 2016-01-05  1.014062  1.002650  1.002819  
> 2016-01-06  0.991911  0.999906  1.014441  
> 2016-01-07  0.937087  0.995280  1.014140  
> 2016-01-08  1.005388  0.999147  0.995572
> ```

```
I have initial weights for each ticker on day one
SPY  50
IWM  25
TLT  25

Each weight has a band
SPY = 40, 60
IWM = 20, 30
TLT = 20, 30
```

The dataframe goes on for 5 years daily.  For the first day I want to calculate the original weight times the return for that day.   For every day after that day, I want to calculate the return of that day (which is the previous day value times that days return) and check each day if the weight of any one of the three is outside the band.   Weight for each day is the value for that ticker / the sum of that days value.  If one of the ticker weights violates the band for 5 days straight, I want to rebalance all three and the next day row should be the original weight divided by the previous days portfolio value.

```
 Example       SPY      IWM         TLT      PortValue    SPYW    IWMW TLTW
    XX Date      51.45     27.25      21.54       100.24     51.3    27.18  21.4 No Rebal,nextday*prevday
    XX Date       59        29         15          103       57       28    14.5  Rebal, next day below
    NEXT DAY  50/103*ret 25/103*ret  25/103*ret
```

I have tried everything.  lambda functions, np.where, for loops, if statements, nested variations of all of the above.  I cant get around the bool test for the index for the first day and make that work with the rest of the days where the next row is contingent upon the calculation of the previous row and not on the datetime index location

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Something along the lines of the following should work - obviously, with many modifications to reflect your actual data. Note that this totally disregards the datetime index since it's informational and doesn't affect the outcome:

```
portfolio = [50,25,25] #starting amount of each investment in the portfolio
allocations =[.50,.25,.25] #base allocations among the portfolio investments
tickers = list(df3.columns.values)
bands = [[.4,.6],[.20,.30],[.20,.30]] #permissible bands for each investment/ticker
violations = {ticker:0 for ticker in tickers} #initialize a violations counter for each ticker

#start iterating through each day in the dataframe:
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    yields = row.to_list() #extract the daily yields
    portfolio = [investment*yld for investment, yld in zip(portfolio,yields) ] #recalculate the new value of each investment 
    weights = [investment/sum(portfolio)for investment in portfolio] #recalculate the new relative weight of each investment
    for weight,band in zip(weights, bands):
        ticker = tickers[weights.index(weight)] #for each ticker - 
        #check if it's outside its permitted band
        if weight<band[0] or weight>band[1]:
            violations[ticker] +=1 #if it is, increment its specific violations counter            
        else:
            violations[ticker]=0 #if not, reset the counter to zero, to account for non-consecutive violations  
        if violations[ticker] == 5: #5 consecutive violations detected....
            portfolio = [sum(portfolio)*allocation for allocation in allocations] #rebalance the portofolio
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will try to work your code.  

The problem is the first row is the starting allocation * first days return.   But every day after that the return is based on the previous days value if no rebalance and a reweighting value if rebalanced and that is based on a column trigger for rebalancing. I hacked a solution that created a new df for every time I rebalanced but I have to lengthen or shorten the code based on how many times a particular portfolio rebalanced.

Comment: Maybe I am not following your example.  But the returns need to compound, but after the rebalance the compounding calculation has to start over.   The way it is written above the yield return does not start over when it is reblanced

Comment: Also, I am having the same issue in that the first row, returns are calculated off of the initial weights, but subsequent rows are calculated based on the previous row value

Comment: @DMike Not sure what you mean. At the end of every day, you take the portion of the value of the portfolio represented by each ticker at the end of the previous day, and multiply that value by the return for the particular ticker for this specific day - so each value of each ticker compounds daily. When you re-balance, the same thing happens, but before you feed the values to the next day's return, you sell some of the overweight/buy some of the underweight tickers (i.e., adjust the values) and on the next day do the same as on the previous day, but using the new values.